# shell_exec not taking Urdu word

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a PHP code in which shell_exec command takes a word and make it as an argument to the jar file (that simply displays the argument yet). But when I echo the result for any Urdu word it displays '?????'

My jar works absolutely fine with English word, but not for any Urdu word.

My code is

```
   <?php
   $q="علی";
   $out="/path/to/jar/myJar.jar  $q";
   $out2=shell_exec($out);
   echo $out2;
   ?>
```

Comment: Note: Please make sure that you use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) when using *any* user input in the shell! Otherwise, look forward to `; sudo rm -rf /`, and have your entire server be gone.

Comment: if you run `/path/to/jar/myJar.jar علی` on the command line of the server, does it work?  also try running something like   `/bin/echo علی > /tmp/test.out` in the shell_exec and see what is getting passed to the shell. (Just trying to narrow down where the problem is)

Comment: @Doon yes  it works fine on the command line of the server. shell_exec is having some issue.

Comment: You need to set the LANG env var first. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028925/call-a-program-via-shell-exec-with-utf-8-text-input