# PHP: How to configure windows shell codepage so that STDOUT of proc_open() does not garble?

Tags: php, windows, shell, encoding

The following PHP code

```
$descriptorspec = array(1=>array('pipe', 'w'));
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('echo こんにちは');

// Change this line in the following snippets
$proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

$res = null;

if (is_resource($proc))
{
    $res = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($proc);
}

echo $res;
```

outputs the gibberish `$res = ����ɂ���`.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028925/call-a-program-via-shell-exec-with-utf-8-text-input) by setting up `$env_vars` in `proc_open()`. That is, I substituted the third line of the above snippet with

```
$encoding = array('LANG'=>'ja_JP.utf-8');
$proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, $encoding);
```

Still outputs the garbled string `$res = ����ɂ���`.

Next, I tried to use `setlocale()` and `putenv()` as per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961870/php-exec-change-encoding). The third line of the first snippet becomes

```
$encoding = 'ja_JP.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $encoding);
putenv('LC_ALL='. $encoding);

$proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

Still outputs the gibberish `$res = ����ɂ���`...

Do you know what's wrong with the shell encoding config?

As a side note, I'm currently debugging my code on Visual Studio 2022 with IIS Express (Win10/11), but will eventually deploy my website on an Apache server.

*Additional info:*

- *I use IIS Express launched from Visual Studio 2022 and an external WAMPServer as debugging servers. Both output garbled results.*
- *The version of PHP is 8.1.*
- *The OS is Windows 11 Enterprise.*
- *My PHP file is correctly saved in UTF-8 (without BOM)*
- *Important note 1: the original code **works** in the PHP interactive shell opened from PowerShell 7.2 64bits.*
- *Important note 2: the original code **works** on another computer using Windows 10 Home.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLTR

Use the PHP function `sapi_windows_cp_conv` as follows.

```
$res = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$res = sapi_windows_cp_conv(sapi_windows_cp_get('ansi'), 65001, $res);
```

### Long Answer

The solution refers to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942172/how-to-convert-output-of-windows-shell-exec-in-php-to-utf8). In fact, PHP communicates with the default command shell of windows (cmd.exe, pwsh.exe, ...), whose codepage might be set to ANSI instead of UTF-8.

First, try to modify the default codepage of cmd.exe following [these steps](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8). However, if encoding issues persist, you might need to look at the next alternative.

To enforce conversion from one codepage to another directly from PHP, use `sapi_windows_cp_conv(sapi_windows_cp_get($kind), 65001, $res)`, where 65001 refers to UTF-8 encoding (see [chcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window)). Please refer to the `sapi_windows_cp_conv` documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sapi-windows-cp-conv.php). Note that `$kind` needs to be specified as `'ansi'` or `'oem'` as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sapi-windows-cp-get.php).

**EDIT**: To set ANSI/OEM of cmd/powershell to UTF-8 *at the system level*, check out [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window).